# Warning: setState(...): Cannot update... when using this.props.change()

Tags: redux-form

I'm using redux-form v6.5.0

I'm trying to save a value in an hidden field and update it when some other value change with `this.props.change('field_name', value)`

On `componentDidMount` i call a function with the form data as parameters who calculate and update my hidden field with `this.props.change('field_name', value)`

This function is called each time one of the other field change.

It's working fine but i have the warning

`` Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`. ``

Here is the full code :

```
class Donnees extends Component {

    componentDidMount () {
        this.calculPreavis(this.props.user)

    }

    calculPreavis = (user) => {
        console.log('calculPreavis');
        if (get(user, 'logement.meuble') === 'true') {
            this.props.change('user.logement.preavis.duree', 1)
            //return 1
        }
        else if (get(user, 'logement.meuble') === 'false') {
            this.props.change('user.logement.preavis.duree', 3)
            //return 3
        }
    }

    render () {

        const {loading, onSubmit, user} = this.props

        return (
            <Form>    
                <Field
                    component={DefaultGroupedButton}
                    name="user.logement.meuble"
                    required
                    validate={required}
                    label="Type de location"
                    elements={[
                        {
                            label: `Meublée`,
                            value: 'true'
                        },
                        {
                            label: `Non Meublée / Vide`,
                            value: 'false'
                        }
                    ]}/>

            </Form>
        )
    }
}
```

Is this a bug ? Or am i missing something ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are trying to set some sort of initial values to your form in `componentDidMount`.

The reason you're seeing that error message is most likely that triggering the `change` function during `componentDidMount` causes some resulting `setState` call down the call stack to happen during some component's `render` for example. The obvious solution is to eliminate the possibility for this to happen.

I recommend setting any form values by injecting an `initialValues` prop to the component decorated with `reduxForm` instead ([see docs](http://redux-form.com/6.6.1/docs/api/ReduxForm.md/)). Check out the [Initialize From State](http://redux-form.com/6.6.1/examples/initializeFromState/) -tutorial in the `redux-form` docs for a more in-depth example.

Comment: Ok. Got it. But how can i update this field after the initialization ? I want to calculate a new value for my hidden field C when field A and field B change.

Comment: You can either use the [change](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/docs/api/ActionCreators.md/) action creator or always recalculate the value for `initialValues` in `mapStateToProps` which will reinitialize the form every time as long as you have set the [enableReinitialize](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/docs/api/ReduxForm.md/) prop `true` for `reduxForm`.